# Fill Embedded PDF from values in Windows Form - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

So I've embedded a PDF in one of my windows forms. It works great, but is there a way for me to populate the pdf with values from another form?

For example, I'd wanna take a comboBox.Text value and place that in one of the PDF's Textboxes.

I was just wondering if there was any solution for me to do this programmatically with C#.

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score -1):

How exactly are you integrate the PDF into your form?
which library you are use?

I'm asking because it depends how to achieve you goals.

For example, yo can use aspose pdf for .net,  patagames pdfium.net sdk,  debenu quick pdf library or something else. iText sharp pdf or ghost library

Comment: This is very poorly written. Please fix the grammar.